# mysql aggregation of table with one value per row

Tags: mysql, aggregation, transpose

I have this source table:

```
source table:
------------------------------
| id | col 1 | col 2 | col n |
------------------------------
| 0  |   1   |  NULL | NULL  |
------------------------------
| 0  | NULL  |   1   | NULL  |
------------------------------
| 0  | NULL  | NULL  |   1   |
------------------------------
| 1  |   1   |  NULL | NULL  |
------------------------------
| 1  | NULL  | NULL  |   1   |
------------------------------
```

There will never be values for two columns in one row (except NULL).

Now I need to transpose it to this target table:

target table:

```
------------------------------
| id | col 1 | col 2 | col n |
------------------------------
| 0  |   1   |   1   |   1   |
------------------------------
| 1  |   1   | NULL  |   1   |
------------------------------
```

I am stuck and yet have the feeling that I am missing some simple trick...?

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

use `MAX()`

```
SELECT  id, 
        MAX(col1) AS col1, 
        MAX(col2) AS col2, 
        MAX(coln) AS coln
FROM    sourceTB
GROUP   BY id
```

since you want to insert this into the target table, you can simple build up an `INSERT` statement like this:

```
INSERT  INTO targetTB (id, col1, col2, coln)
SELECT  id, 
        MAX(col1), 
        MAX(col2), 
        MAX(coln)
FROM    sourceTB
GROUP   BY id
```

Comment: thx 4 the quick answer. exactly what i was looking for. just didn't think of "foreign" use of max...sorry 4 bothering.